# qtextedit: the different color of letters in the middle of the word breaks rtl direction

Tags: html, qt, colors, arabic, qtextedit

In Arabic and Persian languages, the color of the letters can not be changed in words!

```html
<span style="color:blue;">سم<span style="color:red;">ی</span><span style="color:blue;">ع</span></span>
```

HTML: In standard web-based codes in browsers
سمیع
[image]

HTML: in qtextEdit and qtextBrowser
سم ی ع
[image]

Comment: what's your question? could you provide more info?

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA seems that 1st screenshot has text in RTL direction but in 2nd there's LTR

Comment: Both screenshots are right-to-left (RTL direction)

Answer (score 0):

I can use the [Zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) but the problem remains.
Especially in replace.

```
QString html = "&zwj;<span style='color:Red;'>&zwj;رب&zwj;</span>&zwj;";
str.replace("رب",html);
```

1. رب
2. ربنا
3. یضرب
4. تقربا

‍‍رب‍‍ ‍‍رب‍‍نا یض‍‍رب‍‍ تق‍‍رب‍‍ا